# Are there things that AWS CDK or AWS SAM can do that cannot be done on the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-sam

Are there features of AWS that can only be accessed via the AWS CDK or AWS SAM that cannot be done on the AWS console?

Comment: In terms of managing AWS resources: no. But before CDK synths the template it e.g. bundles lambdas and uploads their code to S3, that is not something the AWS console can do automatically but would be something you need to do manually first.